# Aware of differences between people in groups

Tags: single-word-requests

People might claim that a person is *something*-ist, like ageist. But is there a word to reflect that the person is actually not assuming one group is lesser to another but just aware of differences between them?

Comment: Maybe discriminatory? I think we need a sentence with a blank where the word would go.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK "I'm not against anyone, I'm just [blank]" ... I guess!

Comment: Impartialist : One who is impartial. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Impartialist

Comment: @Josh61 I want to highlight that there *are* differences between the groups, unrelated to prejudice. -ist tends to imply that the person thinks one group is inferior, but I want to say the person sees the differences. I'm thinking 'observant', but I don't think that captures the group differences aspect.

Comment: Objective: -  1)undistorted by emotion or personal bias, 
2) of or relating to actual and external phenomena as opposed to thoughts, feelings, etc

Comment: Technically I guess the word should be 'discriminate', but that is loaded with the prejudicial connotation.

Comment: ***Differentiate*** may suggest the same meaning without negative implications . http://www.thefreedictionary.com/differentiate

Comment: @Josh61 I just found that too! Yes, I think that's the word I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*differentiate* -- agreeing with @Josh61 in comments

"I am not ageist, but I can differentiate."

Comment: I never could differentiate very well, and, as for integrals, forget it!

Comment: @HotLicks I would be talking with people who could *differentiate* definitions.

Comment: I think, for speaking fluently, it's more important to *integrate* them.

Comment: I wouldn't want to be on the receiving end of this.  It would still feel like ageism, racism, religion prejudice, sexism, or whatever the speaker is claiming not to be.

Answer (score 0):

Pluralism perhaps? That a range of views are considered and respected. Also as a phrase *catholic tastes*, or liberal, open minded, objectivist.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not against anyone, I'm just _________

**Respectful of differences.**

Comment: No I wanted a word meaning 'aware of differences', and I found one, 'differentiate'.

Comment: @Tom - Good luck using that word and not offending folks who are sensitive about discrimination....